# How to exclude some classes in jacoco:structure

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to exclude some class files since those files do not want to get considered when calculating code coverage.

My scenario is I'm getting .exec file and class files from Jenkins for multiple projects and trying to create one aggregated report. So I'm using jacoco:merge to create the merged exec file and I'm generating the report using jacoco:report. I want to exclude some classes here. But I can't use `<excludes>` inside jacoco:structure.

My code attached here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>wso2</groupId>
<artifactId>code-coverage-report</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>with-tests</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>!maven.test.skip</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-jacoco-dependencies</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                <includeTypes>jar</includeTypes>
                                <includeArtifactIds>org.jacoco.ant</includeArtifactIds>
                                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- Ant plugin - Merge Jacoco Reports -->
                <!-- Logging and distribution modules are not checked since not relevant -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
                                    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
                                        <classpath path="${project.build.directory}"/>
                                    </taskdef>

                                    <jacoco:merge destfile="merged.exec">
                                        <fileset dir="jacoco/exec/" includes="*.exec"/>
                                    </jacoco:merge>

                                    <jacoco:report>
                                        <executiondata>
                                            <file file="merged.exec"/>
                                        </executiondata>
                                        <structure name="Final Coverage Report">
                                            <classfiles>
                                                <fileset dir="jacoco/class/classes/"/>
                                            </classfiles>
                                            <excludes>
                                                **/org/xxx/carbon/dataservices/ui/stub/admin/*,
                                                **/org/xxx/carbon/rest/api/stub/types/aaa/*,
                                                **/org/xxx/carbon/endpoint/stub/types/aaa/*,
                                            </excludes>
                                        </structure>
                                        <html destdir="jacoco/tmp_report"/>
                                        <xml destfile="jacoco/tmp_report/coverage-report.xml"/>
                                        <csv destfile="jacoco/tmp_report/coverage-report.csv"/>
                                    </jacoco:report>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                            <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
                            <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.ant</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.9</jacoco.version>
</properties>

</project>
```

But it gives the following exception. when I try to run it.

```
An Ant BuildException has occured: structure doesn't support the nested "excludes" element.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [documentation](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html):

> ### Task report
>
> #### Element structure
>
> Note that the `classfiles` and `sourcefiles` elements accept any [Ant resource collection](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection). Therefore also filtering the class file set is possible and allows to narrow the scope of the report, for example:
>
> ```
> <classfiles>
>     <fileset dir="classes">
>         <include name="org/jacoco/examples/important/**/*.class"/>
>     </fileset>
> </classfiles>
> ```

Hence

```
<classfiles>
  <fileset dir="jacoco/class/classes/">
    <exclude name="org/xxx/carbon/dataservices/ui/stub/admin/**/*.class"/>
    <exclude name="org/xxx/carbon/rest/api/stub/types/aaa/**/*.class"/>
    <exclude name="org/xxx/carbon/endpoint/stub/types/aaa/**/*.class"/>
  </fileset>
</classfiles>
```